# "None" as plural indefinite pronoun

Tags: grammatical-number, pronouns, uncountable-nouns, indefinite-pronouns

In my grammar book (*English Grammar*, HarperCollins Publishers), I read that *none is occasionally treated as plural, but it is usually regarded as singular*. Can you give me an example of sentence where *none* is used as plural pronoun?

Comment: this question is quite zen; is this actually a koan? :)

Comment: @mfg: If I would know what a koan is, I could reply. ;-) It's a simple question I had when I read the grammar book. After many years I have been taught British English, I wanted to buy a book about American English (I hope the one I bought in USA is really about American English).

Comment: 'A Buddhist monk was asked to discard everything. "But I have nothing," he exclaimed. "Discard that too!" ordered his master.'

Comment: @mfg: I got it. `:-)`

Comment: @mfg: sweet i just became enlightened!

Comment: @mfg So, that's a case where 'none' has a singular verb, yeah?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*None* is commonly used as a plural. You can find many examples in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/). For example, I searched for `none of the [nn2] [vv0]` to find examples where *none* refers to something in plural and then takes a plural verb. (`[nn2]` matches any plural common noun and `[vv0]` matches any simple verb not inflected for third person singular, and so must be plural if used with a plural common noun). There were 117 results that matched, including:

- none of the airlines want
- none of the alternatives look
- none of the americans ask
- none of the answers make
- none of the appeals work
- none of the articles mention
- none of the artists take
- none of the attendants remember
- none of the authors speak
- none of the averages reflect
- none of the bankers quit
- none of the beads come
- none of the birds need
- none of the boys seem
- none of the broadcasts include
- none of the broadcasts use

I also searched for `none of the [nn2] [vvz]` to find examples where the verb *is* inflected for third person singular, and there were just 57 matches, including:

- none of the boys wants
- none of the studies reports
- none of the theories appears
- none of the things quadrupeds
- none of the vaccines addresses
- none of the women sees
- none of the actors knows
- none of the alternatives meets
- none of the authors calls
- none of the books points
- none of the candidates fits
- none of the changes seems
- none of the children knows
- none of the children understands
- none of the clubs pumps
- none of the codes calls

This indicates to me that the “usually regarded as singular” traditional rule is in fact about half as common as the “occasionally treated as plural” exception.

Comment: I think the "usually singular/occasionally plural" ratio is what that prescriptive grammarians deeply *wish* were true, reality be damned :)

Comment: It seems to me that the grammar book gives to _usually_ a different meaning than the one I give to the word. I guess I could say I usually speak Chinese. `;-)`

Comment: (off-topic) what do [nn2] and [vvz] mean? Does google understand them (doesn't seem to)?

Comment: [nn2] and [vvz] are search terms for the Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA), linked at the top of the answer, where I also wrote “[nn2] matches any plural common noun”. [vvz] matches any verb in the present tense inflected for third person singular (i.e. has an -s, as in *wants, reports, appears, addresses*, etc.

Comment: If you do the same queries on the British National Corpus it is even more of a wash (20:15).  BTW it *may* be useful to know that the tagger used on a corpus doesn't always get the POS correct.

Comment: @Chris re:POS tagger—yup, I noticed just a few minutes ago “none of the things quadrupeds” is probably not a valid example.

Comment: “The ‘usually singular’ rule is about half as common as the ‘occasionally plural’ exception”—a phrasing worthy of an eleventy-first birthday party speech!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I prefer thinking of all “a lot/number/handful/X% of the NOUN”– and “some/most/much/none of the NOUN”–type constructions as premodifiers in the NP acting like partitive determiners, not prepositional phrases stealing focus. That way they don’t change the actual head noun, which still governs subject–verb agreement. At least, that’s how people seem to treat them in actual speech. Exceptions occur for *one of the* being always singular and *many of the* being always plural, but the rest are decoys. I’ve no professional references to support this perception, though; I wish I did

Answer (score 22):

*None* is indeed originally from *not one* or *not a/an* (since this happened before *one* and *a/an* became separate words, c.f. how French uses *un/une* for both the number one, and the indefinite article).

At the time that this happened though, it could be declined according to gender, number and case. King Alfred's translation of Boëthius' *Consolatio Philosophiae* (888CE) uses *none* not just plural but in a plural form.

So, even in very early use, while its origins may have been from *not one*, it had a meaning *not any*, and hence could be plural as well as singular.

It's also worth noting at this point, that *no* is also derived from *not one* in many senses (where used as a negative response, it has a different origin; *no* is a merging of two words), and its use with both singular and plural is less controversial (though not without differences of opinion as to just when it should be treated which way).

It would seem that the “logical” argument that *none* must be singular, because *not one/not a/not an* is singular is mistaking the word’s etymology for the word itself.

Of course, in leaving a defence of *none* being used in both the singular and the plural at this point, I could be doing the same thing: After all, Old English had different forms, and we do not. Some forms have given us separate words and we now have *why* as a separate word from *what* rather than their being the same word with different declensions.

It’s perfectly possible therefore, that by Modern English, *none* had become singular. However, it had not:

> I will converse with iron-witted fools
>
> And unrespective boys: **none are** for me
>
> That look into me with considerate eyes:
>
> High-reaching Buckingham grows circumspect.—Shakespeare, “Richard III”, Act IV, Scene ii
>
> Before him there **were none** so beautiful, even from the beginning.—Ecclestiastes 45:15 DV
>
> For the people were numbered, and, behold, there **were none** of the inhabitants of Jabeshgilead there.—Judges 21:9 KJV
>
> **None** that **go** unto her **return** again, neither take they hold of the paths of life.—Proverbs 2:19 KJV
>
> **None were** his **friends** but courtiers and clergymen, the worst at that time, and most corrupted sort of men; and court ladies, not the best of women; who, when they grow to that insolence as to appear active in state-affairs, are the certain sign of a dissolute, degenerate, and pusillanimous commonwealth.—Milton, “Upon The Earl of Strafford’s Death”

So was this a new strictness introduced in the 18th or 19th centuries, when some of the more notorious “rules” in English were introduced?
Lindley Murray’s [English grammar: adapted to the different classes of learners, with an appendix, containing rules and observations for assisting the more advanced students to write with perspicuity and accuracy](http://archive.org/download/adaptedgrammar00murrrich/adaptedgrammar00murrrich.pdf) (1835) argues:

> *None* is used in both numbers: as, “*None* is so deaf as he that will not hear;” “*None* of those are equal to these.” It seems originally to have signified, according to its derivation, *not one*, and therefore to have had no plural; but there is good authority for the use of it in the plural number: as, “*None* that *go* unto her *return* again.” Prov. ii. 19. “Terms of peace *were none* vouchsaf'd” MILTON. “*None* of them *are* varied to express the gender.” “*None* of them *have* different endings for the numbers.” Lowth’s *Introduction*. (Emphasis his).

Interestingly, he cites the “not one” argument for singular-only use, and seems to suspect *none* was once singular-only for this reason, but is quick to reject it. One example quoted is from the KJV as given above, “Lowth’s *Introduction*” mentioned above is Archbishop Lowth’s *A Short Introduction to English Grammar*, so looking at this 19th Century grammarian gives us an 18th Century grammarian for free!

At the same time, it does point to when the edict against plural *none* may have arisen. We might suspect it came with modern style-guides choices being taken as overall edicts upon the language, but that Murray mentions the “not one” derivation **could** mean he is taking the effort to debunk advice found anywhere.

Still, with this bringing us close enough to the current age that we can take the very existence of questions like this on websites like this to bring us through to the home stretch, it’s safe to conclude:

1. *None* can be both singular and plural in use.
2. *None*’s being both singular and plural in use goes back to the earliest days of the language.
3. *None*’s being both singular and plural in use continued through to the earliest days of the modern form of the language.
4. *None*’s being both singular and plural in use was recognised by those who would have been strictest in their opinions on how English should be written.

If nothing else, the form “Almost none…” would seem to forbid the singular,
rather than the plural:

> *Almost none of the apples is edible.

Comment: Brilliant analysis! Thank you for providing this answer.

Comment: (Note that in modern French, [*aucun* (none) is generally singular](http://grammaire.reverso.net/4_2_01_aucun.shtml).)

Answer (score 16):

I wonder if it is talking about [this](http://alt-usage-english.org/excerpts/fxnoneis.html):

> With mass nouns, you have to use the
>   singular.  ("None of the wheat is...")
>   With count nouns, you can use either
>   the singular or the plural.  ("None of
>   the books is..." or "None of the books
>   are...")  Usually, the plural sounds
>   more natural, unless you're trying to
>   emphasize the idea of "not one", or if
>   the words that follow work better in
>   the singular.

Answer (score 5):

The traditional answer is that 'none' should be construed with a singular verb (the rationalisation I remember being given is that it is a contraction of 'no one').

Ordinary people usually ignore this and construe 'none' with a plural.

So the answer is "plural is more common, but some people will criticise you for using it in formal contexts".

Comment: none is not a contraction of no one. If "no one" is what you mean, you should use "nobody", not "none".

Comment: The rationalization you were told was probably that *none* is a contracted form of *not one* rather than *no one*.

Comment: "None shall pass!" -> "Nobody shall pass"?  I'll pass on that.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: @nohat probably has a better rationalization. But I still think it should be plural, even in formal settings.

Comment: @Billy: Well, my comment was supposed to be a joke...

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Oh, I see now. Went right over my head :sigh:

Comment: Actually I think it was contracted before the word 'not' appeared in English. IIRC 'nane' was a contraction of 'ne ane', 'ne' being the general negative particle, which started to be supported by 'noht' ('nought' - literally 'nothing') rather in the same way that French 'ne' has become obligatorily supported by words such as 'pas'.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: That is valid either way, since the form is "shall + infinitive". e.g. you say "Trees shall pass!"

Comment: I thought it meant 'not one'...

Comment: Remember that you can almost always invent some spurious rationalisation for whatever spurious rule you want to invent. I could say that it is more "rational" for verbs to have the ending -s in the plural, not the singular, because that is the pattern observed in nouns.

Comment: @NeilCoffey: and in certain dialects of Middle English, that was the legitimate pattern for verbs.