# Should "none" as a pronoun be used as singular or plural?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [None as plural indefinite pronoun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1425/none-as-plural-indefinite-pronoun)

I was programming when it suddenly struck me that I did not know if "none" should be singular or plural.

Fore instance, should I write "none is yellow", or "none are yellow", if I know nothing more about what "none" refers to?

In [this related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1425/none-as-plural-indefinite-pronoun), it came out that in many instances "none" as a plural indefinite pronoun is completely acceptable. However, that didn't really teach me when to use it as singular or plural.