# Is "none" singular or plural? How can I decide?

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [None as plural indefinite pronoun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1425/none-as-plural-indefinite-pronoun)

With words that indicate portions—some, all, none, percent, fraction, part, majority, remainder, and so forth, how can we decide if the verb will be singular or plural?

> **None** of the garbage was/were picked
>      up. 
>   **None** of the chairs was/were
>      comfortable. 
>   She inspected all of the plates
>      and **none** was/were chipped.

Can anyone please give some more examples and help me out...

Examples:

> None of the pie was eaten. 
>   None of the children were hungry.

In a sentence like “None were missing,” there is an implicit noun that answers the question, “None of what?” That noun is what determines whether none takes a plural or singular verb.

Examples:

> None were missing. (None of the
>      cookies were missing.) 
>   None was missing. (None of the pie
>     was missing.)

Answer (score 5):

From my dictionary:

> **USAGE:** It is sometimes held that **none** can take only a singular verb, never a plural verb: *"none of them is coming tonight"* rather than: *"none of them are coming tonight."*
>
> There is little justification, historical or grammatical, for this view. None is descended from Old English **nān**, meaning ‘not one,’ and has been used for around a thousand years with both a singular and a plural verb, depending on the context and the emphasis needed.

The [OALD](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/) is more specific, saying it depends on the usage:

> **1-** When you use none of with an uncountable noun, the verb is in the singular. EX: *None of the work was done.*
>
> **2-** When you use none of with a plural noun or pronoun, or a singular noun referring to a group of people or things, you can use either a singular or a plural verb. The singular form is used in a formal style in British English. EX: *None of the trains is/are going to London*. / *None of her family has/have been to college.*

Answer (score 2):

It can be both, depending on the subject that goes with it.

From http://www.grammarmudge.cityslide.com/articles/article/1026513/9903.htm:

> A common misconception is that none
>   must always be treated as singular. 
>   The customary support for this view is
>   that none necessarily means "not one"
>   (implying singularity); in fact,
>   "none" is just as likely to imply "not
>   any" (implying plurality).  As noted
>   in The American Heritage Dictionary: 
>   "the word has been used as both a
>   singular and a plural noun from Old
>   English onward. The plural usage
>   appears in the King James Bible as
>   well as the works of John Dryden and
>   Edmund Burke and is widespread in the
>   works of respectable writers today."
>
> The most sensible rule is the one that
>   governs similar words designating a
>   portion of something (fractions,
>   percentages, and indefinite pronnouns
>   such as some, most, many, all, and
>   more).   Just as we write "some of it
>   is" or "two-thirds of it is", we would
>   write "none of it is"; just as write
>   "some of them are" or "two-thirds of
>   them are", we would write "none of
>   them are."
>
> Idiomatically, few of us would be
>   comfortable with "None these people is
>   happy" or "None of my friends is going
>   with me."  The sense here is plural: 
>   not any.  Yet the myth of the
>   singularity of none persists, even
>   among people who frequently say, "None
>   . . . are."  (Why is it that some
>   people cling to a simplistic rule,
>   even when it's wrong, rather than face
>   the necessity of making a choice based
>   on sense?)
>
> When the sense is plural (as indicated
>   by a plural noun or pronoun in the
>   following prepositional phrase – "none
>   of [plural entity]"), none is plural;
>   when the sense is singular (as
>   indicated by a singular noun or
>   pronoun in the following prepositional
>   phrase – "none of [singular entity]"),
>   none is singular.
>
> Futhermore, we may have some instances
>   in which either is correct.  The
>   American Heritage Dictionary notes: 
>   "The choice between a singular or
>   plural verb depends on the desired
>   effect.  Both options are acceptable
>   in this sentence:  None of the
>   conspirators has (or have) been
>   brought to trial."  And that is true
>   because the sense of none may be
>   construed here as either "not one" or
>   "not any."
>
> Two last points are worth noting.  It
>   is difficult to avoid treating none as
>   a plural when it is modified by almost
>   – "Almost none of the children were
>   [not was] well-behaved."  And, in
>   constructions such as "None but a few
>   of the students were able to complete
>   the test," none must be treated as a
>   plural.