# Concept of "none" in the English language

Tags: history, translation, concept

> None of them are/is

I don't know if this is the place to ask, but:

In German you would say "none of them is" and it totally sounds wrong to me to say "none of them are". As German and English are both Germanic languages, I can't explain how they have a different concept of *none*, especially because in French and Italian it's singular as well.

Does anyone know how/why this turned out this way?

Edit:
Before this gets put on hold ;-) I have read a lot of threads about *none*, my question is: how did it become this way? I haven't seen any other threads on that.

Comment: This topic has already been covered many times in [Is "none" singular or plural? How can I decide?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22072/is-none-singular-or-plural-how-can-i-decide) and many other threads.

Comment: There are [77 related questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=[grammatical-number]+none), most of which are closed as a duplicate of that one, which does cover use as early as the ninth century.