# What's the right possessive pronoun for "nobody"?

Tags: pronouns, possessives, personal-pronouns, singular-they

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a correct gender-neutral, singular pronoun (“his” versus “her” versus “their”)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus) 
>   [None as plural indefinite pronoun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1425/none-as-plural-indefinite-pronoun)

Should it be ***his*** or ***their*** here:

A: Why did you put on that baseball cap?

B: Because I want to take shower

A: Nobody takes shower with ***his*** cap on.

Comment: What about the article?  I want to take **a** shower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could leave it as is, but a gender-generic way would be:

> Nobody takes a shower with their cap on.

-or-

> Nobody showers with their cap on.

Comment: ...though some shower with shower caps on.  :)