# When to use "none" as singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

Can someone please tell me which is most appropriate?

(a) "At this time, none of the parties **is** planning to file a motion"; or

(b) "At this time, none of the parties **are** planning to file a motion."

Answer (score 3):

**Either is correct**, although I was taught that "None is" is more appropriate in legal proceedings, where every word matters. After subsequently reading Jon Hanna's excellent analysis in answer to a similar question on EL&U, I can only conclude that what I was taught is not correct. I encourage you to read his answer, which concludes that both uses are equally appropriate in any setting, with a few exceptions as noted. See: ["None" as plural indefinite pronoun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1425/none-as-plural-indefinite-pronoun) for his answer.

Comment: You could also simply use the present tense of the verb: "...none of the parties *plans* to file a motion."

Comment: I think you need to explain why being a legal matter has anything to do with it.

Comment: Why is *"none is"* more formal than *"none are"*?

Comment: @PeterShor Might be within a legal context because there might be a hoard of prescriptivist proofreaders instructed to change *are* to *is* under such circumstances ... :(

Comment: Please see my edited answer. I apologize to anyone I've misled.

Answer (score 0):

None "is." That's the only correct answer. This is a common error. None means "not one," clearly singular. Read it as "Not one is planning to file.." and it becomes obvious.

Answer (score 0):

***None*** stands for "not one"; thus the only correct way to use it here would be ***none is***. As attested by this quote from Lord Byron's *Don Juan*:

In Seville was he born, a pleasant city,
Famous for oranges and women—he
Who has not seen it will be much to pity,
So says the proverb—and I quite agree;
Of all the Spanish towns ***is none*** more pretty,
Cadiz perhaps—but that you soon may see;
Don Juan's parents lived beside the river,
A noble stream, and call'd the Guadalquivir.