# Plurality of "neither of whom"

Tags: grammatical-number

I'm finding myself wondering about which of these you'd find more correct:

> "I went to dinner last night with two young men neither of whom **was** correctly dressed for the occasion"
>
> "I went to dinner last night with two young men neither of whom **were** correctly dressed for the occasion"

The first one sounds right to me, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Just as *none* means *not one*, *neither* means *not either*; and since *not one* is singular, so is *not either*. This means that both *none* and *neither* must be treated as singular.

> **neither** - determiner, pronoun, conjunction, adverb
>   ​
>   B2 not either of two things or people:
>
> - We've got two TVs, but neither works properly.
> - Neither of my parents likes my boyfriend.
> - Neither one of us is interested in gardening.

Cambridge Dictionary

However, see [“None” as plural indefinite pronoun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1425/none-as-plural-indefinite-pronoun). You may be able to use either, but not neither. (singular or plural)

Answer (score 0):

Both singular and plural verbs can be used, the singular is more formal but the plural is and can be used when referring back to a plural noun.